# how to find prime number in 2d array and copy these numbers to another array

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, multidimensional-array

i have a code that create 2d array  by asking user to enter the input than the system check if the elements are prime or not and if they are prime the system will copy them to an 1d array.

i can create the 2d array  but i am stuck in the checking on the prime number and copied to a second array

this is the code

```
    package question6;

    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class MtrixPrime {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            int rows;
            int cols;

            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

            System.out.println("Enter number of row");
            rows = sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Enter number of column");
            cols = sc.nextInt();

            int[][] matrix = new int[rows][cols];

            int[] array = new int[rows];

            System.out.println("Enter numbers in the matrix");

            for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < matrix.length; j++) {

                    if(matrix[i][j] % matrix[i][j] ==0 && matrix[i][j] %1 == 0){
////here i am stuck can anyone help me ??
                        array[i * j];
                    }
                    matrix[i][j] = sc.nextInt();
                }
            }

            for(int row = 0 ;row<matrix.length; row++){
                for(int col = 0 ; col< matrix.length; col++){

                    System.out.print(matrix[row][col] + " ");
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You only have one method in your code, did you forget to include part of it?  Also, what exactly is your question?  Are you getting an error?  If so, what is it?

Comment: Any number % 1 will be 0.  Always.  This is because there is no remainder when dividing by 1 (i.e. every number is divisible by 1).

Comment: no this is the hall code and what i want is to create a multidimensional array than check if the entered numbers are prime or not and the prime number must be copied to another array

Comment: @ Brian i know but i did not find other way to explain my code

Comment: @ JNYRanger sorry for the mistake i did not change the title

Comment: @dvdtel as an aside, if you start typing the `@` and then somebody's name, they'll get a notification that a comment was directed at them, and they can respond easily.

Comment: @dvdtel Also, my point about the % 1 was that it is redundant in your code, and can be removed.

Comment: Are you asking for advice on an algorithm to find prime numbers?

Answer (score 1):

I know it's old post but this might help others.
Used isPrime a boolean flag to save the state of matrix[i][j] value.
If reminder is 0 isPrime will hold false state of matrix[i][j].

Everything is similar like finding prime number of single number. Just have to use 3 for loops for matrix index, before that I have taken matrix values separately.
here's the code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int rows, cols, remainder;
    boolean isPrime = true;

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter number of row and colums : ");
    rows = sc.nextInt();
    cols = sc.nextInt();

    int[][] matrix = new int[rows][cols];

    System.out.println("Enter numbers in the matrix");

    for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < matrix.length; j++) {
            matrix[i][j] = sc.nextInt();
        }
    }

        for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < matrix.length; j++) {

                for (int k = 2; k <= matrix[i][j] / 2; k++) {
                    remainder = matrix[i][j] % k;
                    if (remainder == 0) {
                        isPrime = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (isPrime) {
                    System.out.println(matrix[i][j] + " is a Prime number");
                } else
                    System.out.println(matrix[i][j] + " is not a Prime number");
            }
        }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

One tricky thing to look out for is that since you don't know how many primes you're going to get, and you're using regular arrays, you need a 1d array at least the total size of your 2d array, or you should just use an ArrayList.  If you're set on using a primitive array, you could just add a counter that increases every time you find a new prime, and use that counter value as your index.  This however would leave you with zeros on the back end of your array. If you want your index to correspond to the multi-dimensional array index, you multiply the row index by the number of members in the row, and then add the column index in order to get a 1d index as shown below.  This would leave you with zeros inbetween elements in your array.  Having zeros shouldn't necessarily be a bad thing since it isn't prime, but its still way easier in my mind to use an ArrayList.

```
int[][] nums2d = {{0,1,2},{3,4,5},{6,7,8}};
    int[] nums1d = new int[9];

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            int index = i * 3 + j;
            nums1d[index] = nums2d[i][j];
        }
    }
```